# Imported modules without server side rendering feature

Tags: next.js, surveyjs

I have an issue with Next.js. When I'm trying to import a node module,
the module uses the `window` object and Next.js is throwing an error:  `window is not defined`.

The module is imported like this:

```js
import * as widgets from 'survey-widgets';

widgets.autocomplete(Survey);
```

I guess Next.js dynamic imports will not work in my case. Is there any way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone looking for the solution for this, I solved it with [NextJs Dynamic imports with no SSR](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import#with-no-ssr).

What I did instead is importing my top level component using dynamic import like this:

```
const MyComponent= dynamic(
() => import('../components/hello3'),
  { ssr: false }
)
```

So the `hello3` component will no longer be used in server side rendering and instead it will render on client side.

Then just use it like this:

```
<MyComponent/>
```

Comment: Also to reference your own article this should be useful for the next person bumping into this issue, it helped me a lot https://awixor.medium.com/build-survey-app-using-nextjs-surveyjs-a33745b3a64d

Comment: Good to know that it helps you!

Answer (score 1):

Try deferring all the code that uses `window` or any other `api` that is restricted to the browser, in `useEffect`, because the code in `useEffect` only runs in the browser.

If you can't do that, then make an `intermediary` module which you will use to import `survey-widgets` and re-export what you need. So in the end, you import that `intermediary` module dynamically.

```js
import * as widgets from 'survey-widgets
export default widgets
```